# Not able to set width for button which is in DIV in IE

Tags: html, css, button

I want to reduce the button width which is inside div, but am not able to do in IE8 and above. Please give me some suggestion to solve this problem

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <button title="increase" id="incrBtnvoltageThresholdTol" style="background: rgb(175,      205, 251); top: 1px; width: 22px; height: 13px; font-size: 9px; position: relative;"   type="button"><b>^</b></button>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button title="decrease" id="decrBtnvoltageThresholdTol" style="background: rgb(175, 205, 251); width: 22px; height: 13px; bottom: 4px; font-size: 6px; position: relative;"  type="button"><b>V</b></button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The Code you given above is working fine in IE9+, Mozilla and Chrome. Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/V2CAd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different browsers have different default paddings and margins for controls like buttons.

Solution: specify those measurements explicitly in your stylesheet.

```
padding:0; margin:0; border-width:2px;
```

In addition, you can set the "outline border" for Firefox to 0, which also makes controls look different.

```
button::-moz-focus-inner {margin:0; padding:0;}
```

Then the buttons will have the same dimensions in all browsers. See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/sUPaq/4/).

Comment: You're welcome. By nthe way, I noticed in your code that you set the font size to different values for both buttons, probably because the `^` looked different from the `v`? Try to avoid that kind of thing; it may look better in one font but you're never sure if it looks the same in other fonts. Choose symbols that are comparable with each others (like in my fiddle) or, when in doubt, graphics.